# Recent example for Django in appEngine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

After two days of Googling, I cannot find a recent minimal example of Django usage in GAE.
Most example use CGI or Python 2.5 (I want to avoid that because I want to be threadsafe).

Does anyone have sample code or tutorial that i can look at and learn from ?

This example need to be in Python 2.7 (WSGI, threadsafe).

Comment: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine it's a good place to start from. or tinker a bit with the wsgi script to make it use vanilla django (but I would not recommend that, bit of a pain)

Comment: The allbuttonspressed site is a bit outdated.  See the readthedocs link on the answer below for a more recent version of the same docs.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to run full django? Jinja2 is what I would recommend, but you choose.

Comment: I will take a look at Jinja2. My main goal with Django is to use MVC architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use 'standard' Django with Cloud SQL or django-nonrel with the datastore.

Using standard Django on Cloud SQL would be pretty much the same as using Django anywhere else.  You'll need to set up the database, but otherwise you shouldn't need any GAE specific sample: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

Django-nonrel is a bit more involved, but there's a full sample: http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: The second link is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.